# How do you allow transparent backgrounds on C# controls?

Tags: c#, background, controls, transparent

I've been looking around and I've never found a real direct answer. Right now, I'm trying

```
    public frmGameWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

    }
    private void frmGameWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgSrc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        lblName.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Yet it's still giving the controls above the background color of the parent (in this case, the form itself). I'm attempting to write a very basic game engine to help with my C# studies using strictly features built into a standard install of Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot showing what exactly is wrong. Transparent background on labels definitely works without any extra code.

Comment: Here's the example of what it's doing: http://i64.photobucket.com/albums/h166/Crazy_b1122/Example.png As you can see, the label is still taking the parent's background color (the form).

Comment: What kind of C# controls? Silverlight?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the controls & create your own in which you can Override methods. Here are a few overrides you can try:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

        return cp;
    }
} 
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
    // Don't paint background
}
```

Comment: How do I use this methods?

Comment: Simply put the methods into a class of yours that derives from `Control` and it will override the default behavior.